# Sort list of vectors into single frequency table with a factor column

Tags: r

I have a data frame containing a list vector with jagged entries:

```
df = data.frame(x = rep(c(1,2), 2), y = rep(c("a", "b"), each = 2))

L = list()
for (each in round(runif(4, 1,5))) L = c(L, list(1:each))
df$L = L
```

For example,

```
x y          L
1 a          1
2 a 1, 2, 3, 4
1 b    1, 2, 3
2 b    1, 2, 3
```

How could I create a table which counts the values of L for each x, across the values of y?  So, in this example it would output something like,

```
    1   2   3   4
X
1   2   1   1   0
2   2   2   2   1
```

I had some luck using

```
tablist = function(L) table(unlist(L))
tapply(df$L, df$x, tablist)
```

which produces,

```
$`1`

1 2 3 
2 1 1 

$`2`

1 2 3 4 
2 2 2 1
```

However, I'm not sure how to go from here to a single table.  Also, I'm beggining to suspect that this approach might start taking an unruly amount of time for large data frames.   Any thoughts / suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `pylr`

```
library(plyr)
df = data.frame(x = rep(c(1,2), 2), y = rep(c("a", "b"), each = 2))

L = list()
set.seed(2)
for (each in round(runif(4, 1,5))) L = c(L, list(1:each))
df$L = L

> df
  x y          L
1 1 a       1, 2
2 2 a 1, 2, 3, 4
3 1 b    1, 2, 3
4 2 b       1, 2

table(ddply(df,.(x),summarize,unlist(L)))
>     table(ddply(df,.(x),summarize,unlist(L)))
   ..1
x   1 2 3 4
  1 2 2 1 0
  2 2 2 1 1
```

Comment: I've been considering whether plyr is worth getting into, and this is definitely the motivation I needed.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you're not into plyr...

```
vals <- unique(unlist(df$L))
names(vals) <- vals
do.call("rbind",
    lapply(split(df,df$x),function(byx){
        sapply(vals, function(i){
            sum(unlist(sapply(byx$L,"==",i)))
        })
    })
)
```